# How to add numbers onto the end of an int variable?

Tags: java, methods, int

How would one update an int variable within a method so that an input is added to the end of that int variable?

If I wanted to update the value of a combination after inputting 1, 2, 3, and 4, what can I do to get my variable to hold the value 1234?

Comment: StringBuilder has a append method. Then toString and parse. Another solution is to use the fact that 312 is 3 * 100 + 1 * 10 + 2

Comment: Your question is likely getting down-votes as you're not showing your pertinent code nor your own attempt to solve this. Please improve the quality of this question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that you only add 1 digit integer then you can use this:

```
int i = 12;
int j = 3;

i = i * 10 + j; // here our actual code

System.out.println(i);
```

Result is `123`.

Answer (score 0):

This works,

```
int i = 1;
int j = 2;
int k = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(i) + String.valueOf(j));
System.out.println(k);
```

Output will be 12